# Multiobjective optimization: welded beam design problem

Tags: python, optimization

I am having a hard time with setting the bounds for variables. With the code below I get this error

```
VariableError: The initial value 0.1 should be between the upper (2) and lower (inf) bounds.
```

I know that the welded beam problem doesn't require initial values, so I'm very confused.

```
var_names = ["x1", "x2", "x3", "x4"]

upper_bounds = [2, 10, 10, 2]
lower_bounds = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]

variables = variable_builder(var_names, lower_bounds, upper_bounds)
```

Comment: `variable_builder` is undefined in the posted code.

Comment: ```variable_builder```belongs to a Python package called desdeo_problem

Comment: That should have been included in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function call is missing `initial_values`. Because of that, lower bounds are taken as initials, `upper_bounds` are taken as lower bounds, and upper bounds are set to infinity. Easiest fix: pass lower bounds as initial values (but a more informed guess would be better):

```
variables = variable_builder(var_names, lower_bounds, lower_bounds, upper_bounds)
```

The [signature](https://github.com/industrial-optimization-group/desdeo-problem/blob/master/desdeo_problem/problem/Variable.py#L133) for this function is:

```
def variable_builder(
    names: List[str],
    initial_values: Union[List[float], np.ndarray],
    lower_bounds: Union[List[float], np.ndarray] = None,
    upper_bounds: Union[List[float], np.ndarray] = None,
)
```